# How to avoid component being rendered twice during conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Banner component which will be rendered on top of react native screen.

I want to conditionally render that component inside the parent component without a ScrollView, and inside a child component with a ScrollView.

The parent component returns a navigator and has several routes, and the child component is from one of those navigator routes.

When I switch from the child component route to any other route, two banners show up for a split second.

Anyone know how can I avoid this?

```
const App = () => {

return (
  {route !== 'Dashboard' && <Banner />}
<Stack.Navigator>
 <Dashboard />
 <Payments />
 <Invoices />
</Stack.Navigator>
)
}

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
  <ScrollView>
<Banner /> 
</ScrollView>
)
}
```

Comment: What is the motivation for duplicating the banner? I guess its because on dashboard screen, you want it in the scroll view. In my opinion, it would be better to remove the `<Banner/>` from the `App` component completely, and instead nest it in each of the other children as well. That means theres only ever 1 mounted at one time.

Comment: By the way, the reason it probably shows 2 even though its conditionally rendered is because the `route` takes time to update, and that's probably after any animations you have complete. You might be able to use the `beforeRemove` event to set some state that hides it sooner.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your feedback, All the screens except Dashboard has stack navigation headers on them. So, if I add Banner in individual components, the Banner would appear in between the header and screen.

Comment: Gotcha. I think `beforeRemove` is potentially worth a try. Add that event, and a sert a new state item to hide it in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react navigation you can use option props in your component.
Add option in Payments Invoices and remove `{route !== 'Dashboard' && <Banner />}`.
Ex: `<Payments options={{header: () => <Banner />}} />`
[check the react navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/).

Comment: the screen should scroll on the dashboard, so if I add the Banner on the header, the scroll wouldn't happen

Comment: @arun2567 please see my comments on your original question